# IISExpress crash when running debugging .Net Core application

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I've got 2 .Net Core applications. One is an Asp.Net Core app and the other a .Net Core Web API application.

I used to be able to run the applications locally, but the issue started when I tried to host the web API locally so that I can just call it directly from the Asp.Net app.

Now when I try to run the Web app in VS 2019 I get the following error:
".Net Core Host has stopped working"

This is the error in the event viewer:

> "Faulting application name: dotnet.exe, version: 2.2.27818.2, time stamp: 0x5d09400d
>   Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.16299.1182, time stamp: 0x1e6d3739
>   Exception code: 0xe0434352
>   Fault offset: 0x0000000000046278
>   Faulting process id: 0x3f3c
>   Faulting application start time: 0x01d536e22357e1fc
>   Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe
>   Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
>   Report Id: 208995d6-1027-4558-925a-4c90e4afcd5a
>   Faulting package full name: 
>   Faulting package-relative application ID: "

When I try to run the Web API in VS 2019 I get the following error:
"IIS Express Worker Process has stopped"
This is the error in event viewer:

> "Faulting application name: iisexpress.exe, version: 10.0.18362.1, time stamp: 0xdb637d68
>   Faulting module name: hostpolicy.dll, version: 2.2.27818.2, time stamp: 0x5d094024
>   Exception code: 0xc0000005
>   Fault offset: 0x00000000000057f5
>   Faulting process id: 0x50f0
>   Faulting application start time: 0x01d536e26fbd5827
>   Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe
>   Faulting module path: C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.2.6\hostpolicy.dll
>   Report Id: e287462f-6235-4e20-98d6-f01d9068711b
>   Faulting package full name: 
>   Faulting package-relative application ID: "

I have already repaired the VS 2019 installation, removed IIS from the computer and re-added it again using the "Turn Windows Features on or off" function.

Comment: Have you tried commenting out everything, tried a blank project and cancelling this down? if all else fails and you have something reproducible, report a bug with Microsoft